# React lifts up states on his own... sometimes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've just started working with react.js and have a strange problem, which conflicts react's documentation.

The goal is to make markdown file editor with editing file's attributes.

I've created an App and put some components in it, for example IntegerField. Here's the code:

https://github.com/may-cat/markdown-editor/blob/master/slate/examples/index.js

And here's data, which react tryes to deal with:

https://github.com/may-cat/markdown-editor/blob/master/slate/examples/PRJ-RQ12.json

On changing integer value it calls IntegerField's callback

https://github.com/may-cat/markdown-editor/blob/master/slate/examples/index.js#L318

(in fact, not IntegerField's, but it's parent), method onFieldChange() here it is:

https://github.com/may-cat/markdown-editor/blob/master/slate/examples/index.js#L110

And onFieldChange() on his own *only makes setState for child component*, IntegerField. App should know nothing about this change (according to React documentation).

On form submit in App

https://github.com/may-cat/markdown-editor/blob/master/slate/examples/index.js#L378

I check values in App's state. And here strange things begin.
**For IntegerField with "multiple" attribute**, value lifts up and appears in App's state. For example, for "businessvalue" field.
**For IntegerField without "multiple" attribute**, value doesn't lift up and don't appear in App's state. For "numbers" field in my example.

Why is that happening? What's so wrong?

Comment: You need to distill your problem down to its root, and post a code example (not a repo link) that demonstrates the behaviour you're experiencing.

Comment: A little more context will help here. For reference, we've used React for [Corilla](http://www.corilla.com), which contains a Markdown editor in the manner you mention. I'd love to help but you can improve your question by simplifying the difference between expected and observed behaviour without someone parsing your entire code block there.